# assign a new column in pd.dataframe (pandas) by existing column and defining its starting position

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

assign a new column in pd.dataframe (pandas) by existing column and defining its starting position. (to shift the values of a col;umn up or down)

For example i cretae a new panda dataframe (pd.dataframe), and then from this column, i want to make a new column, that will start from its e.g. 2nd, 3rd, 4rth element, and the rest values to be replaced with a specific value / string. Can this be done easily, in one line?

```
 # Creating a dataframe with 10 ones: 

        ww=pd.DataFrame(10*[1])

    # then try to assign a new column, that will start from its 2nd element
    # however, for soem reason (can you expalin it why?), it places a "nan"     
 # as the first element in that new column.

 ww=ww.assign(ww=ww[1:])
 ww
```

the output given is that:

```
   0   ww
0  1  NaN
1  1  1.0
2  1  1.0
3  1  1.0
4  1  1.0
5  1  1.0
6  1  1.0
7  1  1.0
8  1  1.0
9  1  1.0
```

while the expected output will be:

```
   0   ww
0  1  1.0
1  1  1.0
2  1  1.0
3  1  1.0
4  1  1.0
5  1  1.0
6  1  1.0
7  1  1.0
8  1  1.0
9  1  NaN
```

Comment: Please clarify the question showing input and expected output.

Comment: Question is clarified now (i hope).

Comment: What you want is `ww.assign(ww=ww.shift(-1))`. The contents of the single columned `DF` are shifted one level upwards. As a result, it leaves the last cell as `NaN`. Right now, you are slicing from it's second index till the end which leaves the first cell as `NaN`.

Comment: thanks, i did not know that function! thank you.